# azure-iot-sdk-c submodule/library versions

Tags: azure, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-suite

I want to know how to choose the versions of the dependencies used by azure-iot-sdk-c.
for example, I plan to use:

azure-iot-sdk-c from github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git, release_2018_02_09_after_bump_version(3deb0ca3a8e2d220a50175bef71d16d1650a3a79),

then how do I know the right submodule/library versions for it? for example, the sub-modules in https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-c/releases, github.com/Azure/azure-umqtt-c.git ...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @george, I hope that you will take the time to review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because this question lacks detail on what you have tried already, which makes determining what you are trying to accomplish much harder.

Comment: @george wang, Do you still have problem compiling the azure-iot-sdk-c?

Answer (score 0):

Software and library is managed using the version. And libraries should be designed **backwards-compatible** when the **MAJOR** version is same.

A common way to find the suitable version for GitHub project's sub-modules is looking the release date of that project. For example of Azure-iot-sdk-c_release_2018_02_09, the version sub-module of azure-uamqp-c is 1.x.x published before 09/02/2018, so we can use any version of 1.x.x azure-uamqp-c. And of cause, the recommend version should be the latest version of that **major** version(1.2.3) at present.

More detail about concept of version and sub-modules, you can refer the links below:

[Working with submodules](https://blog.github.com/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/)

[Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else lands here after searching the error message of 3deb0ca3a8e2d220a50175bef71d16d1650a3a79;

I found this (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/doc/master_to_main_rename.md) which refers to azure iot branchn renaming from master -> main on Dec 1st -21, which may explain the trouble finding the reference.

By updating my *.bb file which refers to the github with:
git@linktoyourgit.com **;main**

This will reference the specific branch main to find the correct revision.